# Why do my equations align to the left?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I write as follows:

```
\begin{align*}
c_{\nu^*\cup \{(1,h)\}}(h')&=(7,o) &\mbox{ for all }h\in \{h_1,h_3,h_6\}\\
\overline{c}_{\nu}&=c_{\nu}&\mbox{ for all }\overline{c}.
\end{align*}
```

I would like the words "for all" to be aligned. That is why I put in a `&` before the text box. But when I compile, these phrases become left aligned.

What do I have to do to align "for all"?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Can you please show us a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) from `\documentclass` with `\usepackage` of all necessary packages and the needed body code from `\begin{document}` to `\end{document}` instead of a code snippet. This often helps us to help you. And if you want to have aligned the text you need to tell us aligned to what?

Comment: Dear Schweinebacke: this is my MWE.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
c_{\nu^*\cup \{(1,h)\}}(h')&=(7,o) &\mbox{ for all }h\in \{h_1,h_3,h_6\}\\
\overline{c}_{\nu}&=c_{\nu}&\mbox{ for all }\overline{c}.
\end{align*}

\end{document}

Comment: @Bernard: For `k = 1` you would need 0 `&`'s?

Comment: @Werner: As usual I should have reread my writing before posting…

Comment: Note that for k alignment points, you need 2k – 1 `&` to separate the columns which contain each alignment point.

Comment: Please do not hide essential information in a comment. [Edit your question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/376574/edit) to add all information, i.e, the MWE. We like to have self-explanatory questions.

Answer (score 8):

You could put a `&` sign behind the box. But probably `\text` would be a logical choice too.

[image: alignment]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
c_{\nu^*\cup \{(1,h)\}}(h')&=(7,o) &\text{ for all } &h\in \{h_1,h_3,h_6\}\\
\overline{c}_{\nu}&=c_{\nu}&\text{ for all }&\overline{c}.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

As egreg pointed out in the comments you could also use `&&\text{for all $h\in\{h_1,h_3,h_6\}$}` to make the markup clearer (annotation as text).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
c_{\nu^*\cup \{(1,h)\}}(h')&=(7,o) &&\text{for all $h\in \{h_1,h_3,h_6\}$}\\
\overline{c}_{\nu}&=c_{\nu}&&\text{for all $\overline{c}$}.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `&&\text{for all $h\in\{h_1,h_3,h_6\}}` in the first line and `&&\text{for all $\overline{c}$}` in the second one.

Comment: @egreg Probably a markup decision...

Comment: @sophie don't forget to accept the answer using the green tick :) This gives TeXnician 15 reputation points for their time

Comment: @sophie If it solved your problem consider accepting the answer to mark this question as solved.